# Check whether two VAR model forecasts differ significantly from each other

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, forecasting, econometrics, vector-autoregression

I am currently working on my master thesis, for which I wanted to use forecasts from VAR models (more specifically differenced VAR models) to create policy counterfactual scenarios by adjusting one exogenous variable in my model. 
I do not go into the details here, since my supervisor was satisfied with how I set up the model.

My actual question is a rather simple one, which I couldn't find an answer to: How can I test whether two forecasts differ from each other significantly?

I know the question might seem trivial, but I've never had any formal instruction in using VAR models (except for interpreting them), so I've had to learn everything by myself up to this point. So please be understanding with me. ;) Also, if I've missed some details or information that would be necessary, please tell me and I'll add it as an edit.

Thanks in advance for the tips!

Comment: How do you define a significant difference between forecasts? If you care about which one is more accurate, you can check out the [Diebold-Mariano test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/diebold-mariano/info).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, that is not quite what I meant and I'll add it to my question when I get home. What I am looking for is a way to check whether changing my exogenous variable has a significant effect on my forecasted series. You might think of a baseline forecast and an alternative scenario, which only differ in my exogenous variable. I want to end up with a test that tells me whether changing my exogenous variables has had any significant effect on my forecast. Thank you for the link, though. I might use it in the future. It looks really interesting. :)

Comment: Thinking of how to define a significant difference in your case. Regarding subject-matter significance, you can look at the average absolute difference between the forecasts (or some other measure) and deem whether it is large or small in the subject-matter sense. Regarding statistical significance, it is nontrivial. Different models *will* lead to different forecasts. I wonder what null hypothesis could be sensible...